# Efficient storage of two dimensional data that enables "rotation" of the data by row or column

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I'd like to store a two dimensional array of data that makes it possible to easily "rotate" the data either by row or column.

For example, considering the following initial state

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N O P
```

If I wanted to "rotate" the 3rd ('C') column of data by +2, the result would be:

```
A B K D
E F O H
I J C L
M N H P
```

If I then wanted to "rotate" the 2nd ('E') row by -1, the result would be:

```
A B K D
F O H E
I J C L
M N H P
```

I can envisage how you'd enable an efficient means of rotating *either* by row or column by storing the underlying data as either an array of rows or an array of columns, but being able to do both would presumably result in having one means of rotation being a lot less efficient, as you'd have to carry out operations across each of the arrays in turn.

Then again, I've never tried to solve this type of problem before, so perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have huge arrays, I would not sweat it and use either row or column storage with plain NSArrays as you have mentioned. An alternative implementation would be to use just one array and compute indexes yourself. Finally, there is also the possibility of using a c-array internally. I've implemented all three using 4x4 matrices and the c-arrays are by far the fastest yet the simple nested arrays remain more than fast enough:

```
#import <mach/mach_time.h>

typedef void(^execution_block_t)(void);

double time_execution(execution_block_t aBlock);
double time_execution(execution_block_t aBlock)
{
    uint64_t time0 = mach_absolute_time();
    aBlock();
    uint64_t time1 = mach_absolute_time();
    return (double)(time1 - time0)/NSEC_PER_SEC;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   #pragma mark - Using Nested Arrays
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@interface Simple2DRotMatrix : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *_rows;
}
- (void) rotateRowRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void) rotateColumnRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

@implementation Simple2DRotMatrix

- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _rows = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i=0;  i<4;  i++) {
            NSMutableArray *aRow = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (int j=0;  j<4;  j++)
                [aRow addObject:@(i*4+j+1)];
            [_rows addObject:aRow];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) rotateArrayRight:(NSMutableArray*)array
{
    id value = array.lastObject;
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:array.count-1];
    [array insertObject:value atIndex:0];
}

- (void) rotateRowRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    [self rotateArrayRight:_rows[index]];
}

- (void) rotateColumnRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSMutableArray *col = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:_rows.count];
    for (NSArray *row in _rows)
        [col addObject:row[index]];

    [self rotateArrayRight:col];

    NSEnumerator *values = col.objectEnumerator;
    for (NSMutableArray *row in _rows)
        [row replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:values.nextObject];
}

- (NSString*) description
{
    NSMutableString *descr = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSArray *row in _rows) {
        [descr appendString:[row componentsJoinedByString:@","]];
        [descr appendString:@"\n"];
    }
    return descr;
}

@end


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   #pragma mark - Using 1-D Arrays
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@interface Simple1DRotMatrix : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray    *_values;
    NSMutableIndexSet *_indexes0;
}
- (void) rotateRowRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void) rotateColumnRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

@implementation Simple1DRotMatrix

- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _values = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i=0;  i<16;  i++)
            [_values addObject:@(i)];
        _indexes0 = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
        [_indexes0 addIndex:4];
        [_indexes0 addIndex:8];
        [_indexes0 addIndex:12];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) rotateArrayRight:(NSMutableArray*)array
{
    id value = array.lastObject;
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:array.count-1];
    [array insertObject:value atIndex:0];
}

- (void) rotateRowRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSIndexSet *indexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(index*4, 4)];
    NSMutableArray *row = [[_values objectsAtIndexes:indexes] mutableCopy];
    [self rotateArrayRight:row];
    [_values replaceObjectsAtIndexes:indexes withObjects:row];
}

- (void) rotateColumnRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [_indexes0 mutableCopy];
    [indexes shiftIndexesStartingAtIndex:0 by:index];
    NSMutableArray *col = [[_values objectsAtIndexes:indexes] mutableCopy];
    [self rotateArrayRight:col];
    [_values replaceObjectsAtIndexes:indexes withObjects:col];
}

- (NSString*) description
{
    NSMutableString *descr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"\n"];
    for (int i=0;  i<4;  i++) {
        for (int j=0;  j<4;  j++) {
            [descr appendFormat:@"%@,",_values[i*4+j]];
        }
        [descr appendString:@"\n"];
    }
    return descr;
}

@end



// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   #pragma mark - Using C Arrays
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@interface Simple2DCArrayRotMatrix : NSObject {
    id _values[4][4];
}
- (void) rotateRowRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void) rotateColumnRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

@implementation Simple2DCArrayRotMatrix

- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        for (int i=0;  i<4;  i++) {
            for (int j=0;  j<4;  j++)
                _values[i][j] = @(i);
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) rotateRowRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    id temp = _values[index][0];
    _values[index][0] = _values[index][3];
    _values[index][1] = _values[index][0];
    _values[index][2] = _values[index][1];
    _values[index][3] = temp;
}

- (void) rotateColumnRightAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    id temp = _values[0][index];
    _values[0][index] = _values[3][index];
    _values[1][index] = _values[0][index];
    _values[2][index] = _values[1][index];
    _values[3][index] = temp;
}

- (NSString*) description
{
    NSMutableString *descr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"\n"];
    for (int i=0;  i<4;  i++) {
        for (int j=0;  j<4;  j++) {
            [descr appendFormat:@"%@,",_values[i][j]];
        }
        [descr appendString:@"\n"];
    }
    return descr;
}

@end



int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        static int kLoopSize = 50000;

        Simple2DRotMatrix *mat2d = [[Simple2DRotMatrix alloc] init];

        double t0 = time_execution(^(void) {
            for (int i=0;  i<kLoopSize;  i++)
                [mat2d rotateRowRightAtIndex:i%4];
        });

        double t1 = time_execution(^(void) {
            for (int i=0;  i<kLoopSize;  i++)
                [mat2d rotateColumnRightAtIndex:i%4];
        });

        NSLog(@"2D: Time for %d row rotations: %f",kLoopSize, t0);
        NSLog(@"2D: Time for %d column rotations: %f",kLoopSize, t1);


        Simple1DRotMatrix *mat1d = [[Simple1DRotMatrix alloc] init];

        t0 = time_execution(^(void) {
            for (int i=0;  i<kLoopSize;  i++)
                [mat1d rotateRowRightAtIndex:i%4];
        });

        t1 = time_execution(^(void) {
            for (int i=0;  i<kLoopSize;  i++)
                [mat1d rotateColumnRightAtIndex:i%4];
        });

        NSLog(@"1D: Time for %d row rotations: %f",kLoopSize, t0);
        NSLog(@"1D: Time for %d column rotations: %f",kLoopSize, t1);


        Simple2DCArrayRotMatrix *mat2dC = [[Simple2DCArrayRotMatrix alloc] init];

        t0 = time_execution(^(void) {
            for (int i=0;  i<kLoopSize;  i++)
                [mat2dC rotateRowRightAtIndex:i%4];
        });

        t1 = time_execution(^(void) {
            for (int i=0;  i<kLoopSize;  i++)
                [mat2dC rotateColumnRightAtIndex:i%4];
        });

        NSLog(@"C-Array: Time for %d row rotations: %f",kLoopSize, t0);
        NSLog(@"C-Array: Time for %d column rotations: %f",kLoopSize, t1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
2D: Time for 50000 row rotations: 0.009645
2D: Time for 50000 column rotations: 0.099982
1D: Time for 50000 row rotations: 0.118850
1D: Time for 50000 column rotations: 0.133798
C-Array: Time for 50000 row rotations: 0.001620
C-Array: Time for 50000 column rotations: 0.002277
```

Comment: This is pretty much a model answer. (I was really just checking to ensure I wasn't missing out on some other approach, but you've gone above and beyond as far as I'm concerned.)

Comment: It was my pleasure and having a litte time to kill does help.